# how to get variables from with in the javascript events to outside script

Tags: javascript, php

I'm using javascript change event in this. I'm calling one function. Function has some variables, this variables I want use in some where in script like this:

```
<script>
$('#overview-order-status').change( function() {
    if($('#overview-order-status').val() == 'pending'&& $('#date-    range-select').val() == 'today')
    {
        functionForTodayPending();
    }

    data:[[0,dt1], [1,dt2], [2,dt3]]

    function functionForTodayPending()
    {
        var dt1 = 10;
        var dt2 = 20;
        var dt3 = 30;
    }

</script>
```

but it's not working, please help me how to get those variables from change event

Comment: You need them in Javascript code or in your server side ?

Comment: You've an syntax error in your code. A bracket is missing.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with `php`?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove var from the variables as:

```
 dt1 = 10;
 dt2 = 20;
 dt3 = 30;
```

But don't do this, as this (global variables) can mess up with same variable names from other scripts. Just return from the function as local variables and use it where needed.

Also don't tag this with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use variable in your page so you have to define variable at top of the script and dont declare that variable second time in function or any where only insert value in that

```
    <script>
 var dt1,dt2,dt3 ;

 $('#overview-order-status').change( function() {
 if($('#overview-order-status').val() == 'pending'&& $('#date-    range-select').val() == 'today')
         {
             functionForTodayPending();
         }

data:[[0,dt1], [1,dt2], [2,dt3]]

function functionForTodayPending()
 {

dt1 = 10;
 dt2 = 20;
 dt3 = 30;
}

</script>
```